# Dynamically include cordova JS

Tags: javascript, android, html, ios, cordova

Following JS snippet includes the JS file dynamically,

```
var headID = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
var newScript = document.createElement('script');
newScript.type = 'text/javascript';
newScript.src = 'http://172.26.224.57/ios/cordova-2.2.0.js';
headID.appendChild(newScript);
```

But calling the custom plugin doesn't work on the following call

```
 cordova.exec(onSuccess, onFail, "CustomPlugin", "getName", [tempObj]);
```

However if I include the cordova js file statically like below, it works.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://172.26.224.57/ios/cordova-2.2.0.js"></script>
```

Comment: <quote>calling the cust5om plugin doesn't work</quote>
Sounds very specific. Does calling other functions of the remote script works or not?

Comment: Sorry, remote script works with static import. But none of the custom plugin methods are called with the dynamic inclusion.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried adding your script in a custom cordova hook in `config.xml` to be run at build time ?

```
<hook type="before_prepare" src="scripts/prebuild.js" />
```